# Javascript - populating input box with some value received from ajax rest response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an anchor tag in a page1.html which has an onClick event . This onClick makes a REST API call. The response of this REST API call is then passed to a javascript function , which loads page2.html and an input box on page 2 needs to be populated with the responses value.

Here is the code which loads the new page and tries to populate the input box present on the new page

```
function(response){
document.location="page2.html"; 
$( "#inputBoxID" ).val( response.text );    
}
```

The above code is not populating the input box with id "inputBoxID" present in page2.html. What could be the reason and possible solution?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to just load the page2 an onload() make the ajax call and populate your stuff?

Comment: I dont want to load page2 if the REST API call fails, thats why  I am making the ajax call first and on success i am loading page2

Comment: `document.location="page2.html"; ` you know that makes the browser navigate away from the current page, right? Any js after that call should not be relied upon to execute since the page is unloading

Comment: Going off @JonasGrumann - why not just just go to page2 in the onclick. Then inside page2, make an AJAX call to set the input that is on page2. If you don't want to go to page2 if it fails, then INSIDE page2, add a fail handler to the AJAX. And if the AJAX fails, do `document.location = "other_page.html"`

Comment: As Patrick said, once you leave the page the js is gone and reloaded. You could either save your rest response in the cookies or pass them over to the next page as GET parameters like in page2.html?param1=test&param2=test2

Answer (score 4):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/location

"Though Document.location is a read-only Location object, you can also assign a DOMString to it. This means that you can work with document.location as if it were a string in most cases: document.location = 'http://www.example.com' is a synonym of document.location.href = 'http://www.example.com'."

You are in fact changing the page you are on.  You've now lost the context of your API request.  That code which lived in memory on page1.html is gone now, no way to get it back unless you start pushing that data into localStorage and getting it back on the subsequent call to load page2.html.

Comment: So whats the solution , is there any way to load a new page without the data loss?

Comment: You can use an AJAX call to get page2.html.  You'll have to do a $.AJAX GET request to it, then stuff the body of the response into the page.  Then stuff the response.text from the original request into the input after that document is loaded.

But to be honest, the solution is that you've pretty much over-thought this and designed your app incorrectly from the ground up.  You should rethink your design or use a framework.